# Getting typescript errors while deploying the node app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-native, heroku

I have been trying to deploy my typescript based node server to heroku but getting the following error while deployment

```
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > autoscan-back-end@1.0.0 build
       > rimraf dist && tsc
       
       src/services/notification/notification.service.ts(46,37): error TS2322: Type 'string | ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.
         Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.
       src/services/report/report.service.ts(53,35): error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
         Overload 1 of 3, '(callback?: Callback<ReportType[]>): Query<ReportType[], ReportType, {}, ReportType>', gave the following error.
           Argument of type '{ _id?: string; admin: string | Types.ObjectId; status?: string; containsDublicates?: boolean; stickers?: [Types.ObjectId]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Callback<ReportType[]>'.
             Type '{ _id?: string; admin: string | ObjectId; status?: string; containsDublicates?: boolean; stickers?: [ObjectId]; }' provides no match for the signature '(error: NativeError, result: ReportType[]): void'.
         Overload 2 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<ReportType>, callback?: Callback<ReportType[]>): Query<ReportType[], ReportType, {}, ReportType>', gave the following error.
           Argument of type '{ _id?: string; admin: string | Types.ObjectId; status?: string; containsDublicates?: boolean; stickers?: [Types.ObjectId]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<ReportType>'.
             Type '{ _id?: string; admin: string | Types.ObjectId; status?: string; containsDublicates?: boolean; stickers?: [Types.ObjectId]; }' is not assignable to type '{ _id?: any; admin?: Condition<string>; status?: Condition<string>; containsDublicates?: Condition<boolean>; stickers?: Condition<[ObjectId]>; ... 55 more ...; validateSync?: Condition<...>; }'.
               Types of property 'admin' are incompatible.
                 Type 'string | ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.
                   Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.
         Overload 3 of 3, '(filter: FilterQuery<ReportType>, projection?: any, options?: QueryOptions, callback?: Callback<ReportType[]>): Query<...>', gave the following error.
           Argument of type '{ _id?: string; admin: string | Types.ObjectId; status?: string; containsDublicates?: boolean; stickers?: [Types.ObjectId]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FilterQuery<ReportType>'.
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

the project is running smoothly without any error locally, getting this on heroku only

Answer (score 0):

Actually ts was checking the query response from mongodb, which was ignored in other functions but not these.

So I just added //@ts-ignore before the line 53 and 46 to ingore just like other query functions